# Not getting proper scrollview in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, scrollview, coronasdk

I am getting problem in scoreboard viewing. I am giving initial values to my scrollview and contents in scrollview. When initially I am opening my score board, the contents are showing at correct position, but when I am scrolling it down and then up, it is not getting its initial position.
Please check the attached screenshots of the scoreboard view. Can anyone tell me what to do in this condition?

Thanks in advance.

```
local function scrollListener( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    if phase == "began" then 
        print( "Scroll view was touched" )
        for key,value in pairs(event) do 
            print("pranav",key,value) 
        end

    elseif phase == "moved" then 
        --print( "Scroll view was moved" )
        print("over",event.x)

        if(event.x>414)then
            event.x=358
        end

    elseif phase == "ended" then
        print( "Scroll view was released" )
        print("ended",event.x)
    end

    -- In the event a scroll limit is reached...
    if event.limitReached then
        if event.direction == "up" then 
            print "Reached top limit" 
        elseif event.direction == "down" then 
            print "Reached bottom limit" 
        elseif event.direction == "left" then 
            print "Reached left limit"
        elseif event.direction == "right" then 
            print "Reached right limit" 
        end
    end

    return true
end

scrollView = widget.newScrollView
{
    top = 200,
    left = 250,
    width = 500,
    height = 400, 

    scrollWidth = 500,
    scrollHeight = 10,

    topPadding = 0,
    bottomPadding = 0,
    leftPadding = 0,
    rightPadding = 0,

    friction = .972 , -- how fast the scroll view moves.  default is .972

    hideBackground = true, -- if true it wont show the background color.
    horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
    verticalScrollDisabled = false,          

    listener = scrollListener,
}
```

[image: Initial View of score board before scrolling]

[image: After Once scrolling down and then scrolling up]

Comment: There is too much code. Please remove all code that is not directly related (code which, when removed, does not remove problem).

Comment: I have removed other line of code which is not related. Please check now.

Comment: OK this is a lot better but you removed a little too much :) The above is not sufficient to reproduce the problem: you need to add content to the view. I made an assumption about how you do that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is missing code showing the content addition, i.e. with just the code in your question the problem cannot be reproduced. One problem with posted code is `height` vs `scrollHeight`:

Your scroll text `height` is supposed to be the height on screen; its `scrollHeight` is supposed to be the "virtual height", i.e. total height that the widget would occupy if it were not scrollable. So the `scrollHeight` must be large enough to show all display objects that you insert in it, whereas the `height` is just the "window" (portion) that you want to show. Same goes for `width` vs `scrollWidth`, but you are not using horizontal scroll so it is not a concern right now.

Also I could not find any reference to padding properties (topPadding etc) but having them did not cause any problems for me.

I added the following after your code:

```
local function createText(text, y)
    local scrollText = display.newText {
        text=text, y=y, font=native.systemFont, fontSize=20 }
    scrollText.anchorX = 0
    return scrollText
end
scrollView:insert(createText("Hi",    10))
scrollView:insert(createText("Bye",   30))
scrollView:insert(createText("Hello", 50))
scrollView:insert(createText("Hi",    70))
scrollView:insert(createText("Bye",   90))
scrollView:insert(createText("Hello", 110))
scrollView:insert(createText("Hi",    130))
scrollView:insert(createText("Bye",   150))
scrollView:insert(createText("Hello", 170))
```

When created with

```
scrollView = widget.newScrollView
{
    ...

    width = 200,
    height = 100, -- portion of scrollable area you want to see

    scrollWidth = 200,
    scrollHeight = 200, -- complete content area

    ...
}
```

(just shoing differences from your code) it worked fine. I.e., swap the `height` and `scrollHeight` values.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but it still giving the same problem. As I am giving "topvalue" to the contents in the scrollview, after scrolling down and then up, it is not getting the same value to scrollview.

Comment: @Akshada-Systematix Then only option is for you to create a standalone example: extend the code you posted with some content in the scroll view that demonstrates the issue, such that I can copy it into my corona and test it. Note: update your question, do not post a link to codepad or whatever.